# Why my C# syntax doesnt register in vscode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, opengl, syntax-error

so i when i use vs code for c# the syntax wont work example:
'
using System;
'
it wont do anything if tried to run it it wont work,

i alredy tried to reinstall vs code
and still not working, the plugins its all updated
plz help me

Answer (score 1):

C# language support is provided with the C# Dev Kit extension. You can install it from within VS Code by searching for 'C# Dev Kit' in the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X)

See more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: I alredy use c# dev kit but its still wont work